# running multiple java jetty instances with same port (80)

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, subdomain, virtualhost

**For Example:**

I am having one primary temp domain

```
www.product.com
```

For each client i need to have separate sub domain mapped to same server with same port(80) but with different  instance name (different .wars files)

```
www.client1.product.com
www.client2.product.com
www.clientn.product.com
```

(correct me if i am wrong) As i know if i start jetty instance , each will start at seperate port no's

```
client1 war will start at port 3001
client2 war  will start at port 3002
client3 war will start at port 3003
```

What my question is how do i map all the instances with port 80 with appropriate identical sub domains

if i access

`www.client4.product.com` , i need to get jetty app running in port 3004

**Update:**

for more understanding of my architecture , if client2 jetty instance running on port 3002 went to down state due to runtime exception or memory leakage or manual restart , all other jetty instances running independently (similar to architecture behind google appengine uses jetty)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this, don't run multiple Jetty instances. Run one instance with multiple VirtualHosts. To do this, you can configure jetty like this:

```
  <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/client1.war</Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="virtualHosts">
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>www.client1.product.com</Item>      
      </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/client2.war</Set>
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>www.client2.product.com</Item>      
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Check [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts#Configuring_Different_Webapps_for_Different_Virtual_Hosts.2C_But_at_the_Same_Context_Path) out for more information on how to configure this.

Alternatively, if you really want to have multiple Jetty instances, you can front it with another server like Apache that acts as a reverse proxy. Apache can then be set up with virtual hosts by editing your httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.client1.product.com
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPass / http://someInternalHost:3001/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://someInternalHost:3001/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.client2.product.com
     ProxyRequests off
     ProxyPass / http://someInternalHost:3001/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://someInternalHost:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

You can see the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) for more info.

Comment: As per your suggestion , single jetty instances serving all clients, if jetty fails or i need to update code base or restart all the clients unable to access the app

Comment: For the code redeployment issue, you can use jetty's hot deployment so you don't need to restart. But for the case where you have to restart the server, there isn't much you can do unless you have 2 servers behind a load balancer.  You can't have 2 jetty instances bound to the same port so if you really need separate jetty servers, you need to front it with another server. You could use Apache with a similar VirtualHost configuration to forward to the correct jetty server.

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for answering. i updated my question for more clarity, can you please post jetty + Apache virtual host set up for my architecture.

Comment: Are those configurations going into "jetty.xml" or do you guys have other suggestions?