# jetty: how to programmatically configure multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: java, jetty, subdomain, virtualhost, embedded-jetty

I have the following simple embedded Jetty 9 server:

```
    final Server server = new Server();
    final ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(443);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
    server.setHandler(new FooBarHandler());
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Requests to both https://foo.bar.com/ and https://baz.bar.com/ are handled by this code. I want to change it so that:

- Requests to foo.bar.com go to FooBarHandler
- Requests to baz.bar.com go to BazBarHandler
- All of this config needs to be programmatically, not configuration files.

I'm familiar with 
"[running multiple java jetty instances with same port (80)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184479/running-multiple-java-jetty-instances-with-same-port-80)" and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts#Configuring_Virtual_Hosts
but can't seem to get it right programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as in the xml-based configuration, the virtualHost property is within  `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.setVirtualHosts(String[] vhosts)`. So, my guest is that the straightforward way is:

```
ContextHandler fooContextHandler = new ContextHandler("/");
fooContextHandler.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"foo"});
fooContextHandler.setHandler(new FooBarHandler());

ContextHandler bazContextHandler = new ContextHandler("/");
bazContextHandler.setVirtualHosts(new String[]{"baz"});
bazContextHandler.setHandler(new BazBarHandler());

HandlerCollection handler = new HandlerCollection();
handler.addHandler(fooContextHandler);
handler.addHandler(bazContextHandler);

server.setHandler(handler);
```